# Error C0000142 when Starting a Process

Tags: c#, windows, security, process

I am trying to start a process under a different account (setting StartInfo.UserName/Password).

This works when run interactive but fails with error -1073741502 (C0000142; "DLL Initialization Failed") when trying to run it from a process that was started via the Task Scheduler.

I've tried to switch to the WIN32 API and to create a new WindowStation with STARTUPINFO.lpDesktop="" but I get the same error.

**Update**: I just found a related question, unfortunately it is also missing an answer: [Permissions problem when starting .NET app from .NET service as a different user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083299/permissions-problem-when-starting-net-app-from-net-service-as-a-different-user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it working using CreateProcessAsUser from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362419/using-process-start-to-start-a-process-as-a-different-user-from-within-a-windo) and adding LoadUserProfile from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125810/A-complete-Impersonation-Demo-in-C-NET).

Without LoadUserProfile a lot of tools will not work and give you strange errors because they need a home directory (e.g. svn.exe and mstest.exe).